# How to add the Facebook SDK into Cordova 11 Android app without Build fail?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, facebook-sdk-4.0

Ive been trying to add the Facebook SDK into my Cordova Android app but every plugin Ive used crashed the subsequent build. Below are my Cordova specs

```
Cordova 11.1.0
Android 10.1.2
```

Below are the plugins used in my app

```
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.1.2 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-androidx 3.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.13 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-background-fetch 7.1.1 "CDVBackgroundFetch"
cordova-plugin-badge-fix 0.8.10 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 4.0.0 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-contacts-phonenumbers 0.0.12 "Contacts Phone Numbers"
cordova-plugin-device 2.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-exclude-files 1.0.1 "Exclude Files"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 16.0.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-local-notification-12 0.1.4 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 6.0.0 "Splashscreen"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
```

Ive tried the following plugins and all have failed

```
cordova-plugin-fbsdk 
cordova-plugin-facebook-connect
phonegap-facebook-plugin
```

Is there a way to insert the SDK manually or a plugin that is compatible with the versions and settings above.

Thanks